# Use Manipulate function in Mathematica to fit function to data

Tags: wolfram-mathematica, curve-fitting

I want to use the Manipulate function in Mathematica to fit an analytical function to a set of (x,y) data.  I want to plot the dataset on the same axes that I use to manipulate the function (so I can get a visual check of how manipulating the parameters improves the fit, but I cannot find the correct syntax to draw the points behind the manipulated curve.  Any solutions to this?  Many thanks!

Answer (score 1):

Show[plot1,plot2,...] will overlay the plots, see the docs on Show.

```
In[1]:= data = Table[{x, x^2+2*x+RandomReal[{-.1,.1}]}, {x,-3,3}];
  Manipulate[
    Show[ListPlot[data], Plot[a*x^2 + b*x + c, {x, -3, 3}]],
    {{a, 0}, -4, 4}, {{b, 0}, -4, 4}, {{c, 2}, -4, 4}]

Out[1]= ...PlotSnipped...
```